# Can wildcards be used in https functions in Firebase? Alternatively how to make a copy of every document in a database without it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, https, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a https function in google cloud functions that when called will make copies of a document in a Firebase database add an ID and timestamp to the copy and save it to a collection in Firestore. This function will repeat for a certain amount of time for a given interval. For example it if told to run for 2 minutes making a copy every 10 seconds, it will make 12 unique copies saved to Firestore when it is finished running.
Now I have already implemented this function for each specific document in the Firebase database. However this is not scalable. If I were to eventually have 1000 documents in the database then I would need 1000 unique functions. So I want a single https function that will make a copy of every document in the database add the unique id and time stamp to the copy before saving it to Firestore at its unique path.
Here is an example of what I have.

```
// Duration of function runtime in minutes
var duration = 2;
// interval in which the funtion will be called in seconds
var interval = 10;

// Make a Copy of doc 113882052 with the selected duration, interval, and runtime options
exports.makeCopy_113882052 = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  var set_duration = 0; // Counter for each iteration of runEveryXSeconds
  var functId = setInterval(runEveryXSeconds, (interval * 1000) ); //runEveryXSeconds will run every interval in milliseconds
  // runEveryXSeconds will based on the desired parameters
  function runEveryXSeconds() {
    // If runEveryXSeconds has reached its last iteration clear functID so that it stops running after one last iteration
    if(set_duration >= ((duration * 60 / interval) - 1)) {
      console.log("have made ",((duration * 60 / interval) - 1)," copies will now exit after one last copy");
      clearInterval(functId);
    }
    set_duration++; // Increment set_duration at the beginning of every loop
    console.log("Add a charger every ", interval, " seconds until ", duration, " min is up! currently on iteration ", set_duration);
    // grab a snapshot of the database and add it to firestore
    admin.database().ref('/113882052').once('value').then(snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val(); // make a copy of the snapshot
      data.station_id = "113882052"; // add the station id to the copy
      data.timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); // add the current server timestamp to the copy
      admin.firestore().collection('copies/113882052/snapShots').add(data); // add the copy to firestore at the given path
      // only return promis when all iterations are complete 
      if (set_duration >= (duration * 60 / interval)) {
        console.log("return successfully");
        response.status(200).send('Success'); // send success code if completed successfully 
      }
    return null;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error at promise');
      response.send(error); // send error code if there was an error
      return null;
    });
  } // End of runEveryXSeconds
}); // End of makeCopy_113882052
```

So this function here makes a copy of doc 113882052 from Firebase adds the station_id "113882052" and the currant time stamp to the copy and saves it to Firestore collection at the path "copies/113882052/snapShots". It does this 12 times.
All of the other docs and their associated functions work the same way, just swap out the 9 digits for a different 9.
My initial though process is to use wildcards, but those are only used with triggers like onCreate and onUpdate. I am not using these, I am using once(), so I am not sure this is possible.
I have tried swapping out the once() method with onUpdate() like so

```
    functions.database.ref('/{charger_id}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const before_data = change.before.val();
      const after_data = change.after.val();
      //const keys = Object.keys(after_data);
      var data = change.after.val();
      var sta_id = context.params.charger_id;
      data.station_id = sta_id; // add the station id to the copy
      data.timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); // add the current server timestamp to the copy
      admin.firestore().collection('chargers/', sta_id, '/snapShots').add(data); // add the copy to firestore at the given path
    
      // only return promise when all iterations are complete 
      if (set_duration >= (duration * 60 / interval)) {
        console.log("return successfully");
        response.status(200).send('Success'); // send success code if completed successfully 
      }
       return null;
    });
```

but it does not work. I believe it does not work because it would only make a copy if the doc was updated just as the function was called, but I am not sure.

Is there a  way to use wild cards to achieve what I want, and is there another way to do this without wildcards?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of all nodes in the Realtime Database, you'll need to read the **root node** of the database.

So instead of `admin.database().ref('/113882052')`, you'd start with `admin.database().ref()`. Then in the callback/completion handler, you loop over the children of the snapshot:

```
admin.database().ref().once('value').then(rootSnapshot => {
  rootSnapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
    var data = snapshot.val(); // make a copy of the snapshot
    data.station_id = snapshot.key; // add the station id to the copy
    data.timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); // add the current server timestamp to the copy
    ...
  })
```